# Script hangs when passing large amount of text to a multiprocessing.Queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, multiprocessing

So if I understand the answer given in the duplicate original question. I should read the queue before attempting to join, yes? I swapped the queue get loop with the join loop, and still wound up with a stall (but figured reading the queue so soon would be an issue anyway, so I added a 15 second delay after launching the jobs before reading the queue, and saw teh queue read kick off, but still no join. Is there a way to loop through the queues on my job list until all data is read? And would multiple reads work OK considering I am trying to put just one Dict, with a large entry?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pprint
import csv
import paramiko

def main(argv):
  routers = dict(csv.reader(open('routers-sm.csv','r')))
  print ("Number of CPU's I have: ",mp.cpu_count())
  result_queue = mp.Queue()
  jobs = []
  for hn in routers:
    pname="worker_"+hn
    ip=routers[hn]
    process = mp.Process(name=pname, target=ssh_gather, args=(username,password,ip,result_queue))
    jobs.append(process)
    process.start()
  time.sleep(15)
  results = {}
```

`      for p in jobs:
        results.update(result_queue.get())

```
  for p in jobs:
    p.join()

  pprint.pprint(results)


 def ssh_gather(username,password,ip,result_queue):
    ssh_dict = {}
    ssh_dict[ip] = {}
    remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
    remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, username=username, password=password, allow_agent=False, look_for_keys=False)
    remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
    ssh_dict[ip]['config'] = ""
    remote_conn.send("show running-config\n")
    time.sleep(15)
    output = remote_conn.recv(100000).decode("utf-8")
    print("Process {0} targeting IP {1} grabbed config of {2} bytes.".format(mp.current_process().name,ip,len(output)))
    #ssh_dict[ip]['config'] = "Fake Text that is small enough"
    ssh_dict[ip]['config'] = output
    remote_conn.close()
    result_queue.put(ssh_dict)
```

What can I do to fix the issue?